# can't import local jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-ui-theme

I need to use a **local** jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js (not http, from the internet, because of custon themes I have desighned). 
But now I don't have jquery mobile items (popup and slider for example).
My application is phonegap and has cordova-2.6.0.js file.

Here are the links at the head of index.html:
(I **do not** use `jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css` because I want to use **my** themes)

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">-->

    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\rv\workspace\test1\assets\www\css\themes\SensorsTheme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css" />
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\r\workspace\test1\assets\www\jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" />-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
```

And here is the popup that doesn't seem well:

```js
function aboutPopup(popupHeader, popupContent) {
            var $aboutPopup = $("<div/>").popup({
                theme: "c",
                dismissible: false,
            });

            //create a title for the popup
            $("<h2/>", {
                text: popupHeader
            }).appendTo($aboutPopup);

            //create a content for the popup
            $("<h3/>", {
            }).html(popupContent).appendTo($aboutPopup);
```

This is the theme.css I've created by ThemeRoller tool of jquery mobile:

```css
ui-bar-a {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff /*{a-bar-border}*/;
    background: #006FD0 /*{a-bar-background-color}*/;
    color: #ffffff /*{a-bar-color}*/;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 /*{a-bar-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{a-bar-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{a-bar-shadow-radius}*/ #444444 /*{a-bar-shadow-color}*/;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #007ae4 /*{a-bar-background-start}*/), to( #0063bb /*{a-bar-background-end}*/)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #007ae4 /*{a-bar-background-start}*/, #0063bb /*{a-bar-background-end}*/); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( #007ae4 /*{a-bar-background-start}*/, #0063bb /*{a-bar-background-end}*/); /* FF3.6 */
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( #007ae4 /*{a-bar-background-start}*/, #0063bb /*{a-bar-background-end}*/); /* IE10 */
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( #007ae4 /*{a-bar-background-start}*/, #0063bb /*{a-bar-background-end}*/); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image:         linear-gradient( #007ae4 /*{a-bar-background-start}*/, #0063bb /*{a-bar-background-end}*/);
}
.ui-bar-a .ui-link-inherit {
    color: #ffffff /*{a-bar-color}*/;
}
.ui-bar-a a.ui-link {
    color: #7cc4e7 /*{a-bar-link-color}*/;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-bar-a a.ui-link:visited {
    color: #2489ce /*{a-bar-link-visited}*/;
}
.ui-bar-a a.ui-link:hover {
    color: #2489ce /*{a-bar-link-hover}*/;
}
.ui-bar-a a.ui-link:active {
    color: #2489ce /*{a-bar-link-active}*/;
}
.ui-bar-a,
.ui-bar-a input,
.ui-bar-a select,
.ui-bar-a textarea,
.ui-bar-a button {
     font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif /*{global-font-family}*/;
}
.ui-body-a,
.ui-overlay-a {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff /*{a-body-border}*/;
    color: #ffffff /*{a-body-color}*/;
    background: #006FD0 /*{a-body-background-color}*/;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #006fd0 /*{a-body-background-start}*/), to( #006fd0 /*{a-body-background-end}*/)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #006fd0 /*{a-body-background-start}*/, #006fd0 /*{a-body-background-end}*/); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( #006fd0 /*{a-body-background-start}*/, #006fd0 /*{a-body-background-end}*/); /* FF3.6 */
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( #006fd0 /*{a-body-background-start}*/, #006fd0 /*{a-body-background-end}*/); /* IE10 */
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( #006fd0 /*{a-body-background-start}*/, #006fd0 /*{a-body-background-end}*/); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image:         linear-gradient( #006fd0 /*{a-body-background-start}*/, #006fd0 /*{a-body-background-end}*/);
}
.ui-overlay-a {
    background-image: none;
    border-width: 0;
}
.ui-body-a,
.ui-body-a input,
.ui-body-a select,
.ui-body-a textarea,
.ui-body-a button {
     font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif /*{global-font-family}*/;
}
.ui-body-a .ui-link-inherit {
    color: #ffffff /*{a-body-color}*/;
}
.ui-body-a .ui-link {
    color: #ffffff /*{a-body-link-color}*/;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-body-a .ui-link:visited {
    color: #9273c4 /*{a-body-link-visited}*/;
}
.ui-body-a .ui-link:hover {
    color: #c3e0f9 /*{a-body-link-hover}*/;
}
.ui-body-a .ui-link:active {
    color: #9273c4 /*{a-body-link-active}*/;
}
.ui-btn-up-a {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc /*{a-bup-border}*/;
    background: #eeeeee /*{a-bup-background-color}*/;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2f3e46 /*{a-bup-color}*/;
    text-shadow: 0 /*{a-bup-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{a-bup-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{a-bup-shadow-radius}*/ #ffffff /*{a-bup-shadow-color}*/;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #ffffff /*{a-bup-background-start}*/), to( #f1f1f1 /*{a-bup-background-end}*/)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #ffffff /*{a-bup-background-start}*/, #f1f1f1 /*{a-bup-background-end}*/); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( #ffffff /*{a-bup-background-start}*/, #f1f1f1 /*{a-bup-background-end}*/); /* FF3.6 */
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( #ffffff /*{a-bup-background-start}*/, #f1f1f1 /*{a-bup-background-end}*/); /* IE10 */
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( #ffffff /*{a-bup-background-start}*/, #f1f1f1 /*{a-bup-background-end}*/); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image:         linear-gradient( #ffffff /*{a-bup-background-start}*/, #f1f1f1 /*{a-bup-background-end}*/);
}
.ui-btn-up-a:visited,
.ui-btn-up-a a.ui-link-inherit {
    color: #2f3e46 /*{a-bup-color}*/;
}
.ui-btn-hover-a {
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb /*{a-bhover-border}*/;
    background: #dfdfdf /*{a-bhover-background-color}*/;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2f3e46 /*{a-bhover-color}*/;
    text-shadow: 0 /*{a-bhover-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{a-bhover-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{a-bhover-shadow-radius}*/ #ffffff /*{a-bhover-shadow-color}*/;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #f6f6f6 /*{a-bhover-background-start}*/), to( #e0e0e0 /*{a-bhover-background-end}*/)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #f6f6f6 /*{a-bhover-background-start}*/, #e0e0e0 /*{a-bhover-background-end}*/); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( #f6f6f6 /*{a-bhover-background-start}*/, #e0e0e0 /*{a-bhover-background-end}*/); /* FF3.6 */
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( #f6f6f6 /*{a-bhover-background-start}*/, #e0e0e0 /*{a-bhover-background-end}*/); /* IE10 */
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( #f6f6f6 /*{a-bhover-background-start}*/, #e0e0e0 /*{a-bhover-background-end}*/); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image:         linear-gradient( #f6f6f6 /*{a-bhover-background-start}*/, #e0e0e0 /*{a-bhover-background-end}*/);
}
.ui-btn-hover-a:visited,
.ui-btn-hover-a:hover,
.ui-btn-hover-a a.ui-link-inherit {
    color: #2f3e46 /*{a-bhover-color}*/;
}
.ui-btn-down-a {
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb /*{a-bdown-border}*/;
    background: #d6d6d6 /*{a-bdown-background-color}*/;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2f3e46 /*{a-bdown-color}*/;
    text-shadow: 0 /*{a-bdown-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{a-bdown-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{a-bdown-shadow-radius}*/ #ffffff /*{a-bdown-shadow-color}*/;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #d0d0d0 /*{a-bdown-background-start}*/), to( #dfdfdf /*{a-bdown-background-end}*/)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #d0d0d0 /*{a-bdown-background-start}*/, #dfdfdf /*{a-bdown-background-end}*/); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( #d0d0d0 /*{a-bdown-background-start}*/, #dfdfdf /*{a-bdown-background-end}*/); /* FF3.6 */
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( #d0d0d0 /*{a-bdown-background-start}*/, #dfdfdf /*{a-bdown-background-end}*/); /* IE10 */
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( #d0d0d0 /*{a-bdown-background-start}*/, #dfdfdf /*{a-bdown-background-end}*/); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image:         linear-gradient( #d0d0d0 /*{a-bdown-background-start}*/, #dfdfdf /*{a-bdown-background-end}*/);
}
.ui-btn-down-a:visited,
.ui-btn-down-a:hover,
.ui-btn-down-a a.ui-link-inherit {
    color: #2f3e46 /*{a-bdown-color}*/;
}
.ui-btn-up-a,
.ui-btn-hover-a,
.ui-btn-down-a {
     font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif /*{global-font-family}*/;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are experiencing?
Can you provide any error messages, log files, server- or browser-logs? From here I can not see any error.

Comment: where u put that js file ? check the path first then name if your js inside any "xyz" folder then use "./xyz.jquery.js"